# How to change datestyle in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

In postgres I have a table with date column. Now postgres allows me to write date in Y-m-d format. But I need date in d/m/Y format. How to change it?

When I do:

```
   show datestyle;
```

I get:

```
 "ISO, DMY"
```

And input date in table in this format `13/02/2009`

But when I close and open table again I see this `2009-02-13`. JDBC gives me date in this format too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend that you talk to you database using ISO 8601 formats and leave formatting issues for a different layer.

Comment: @muistooshort Absolutely. Before edits this question appeared to be a garbled version of "how do I use to_char to format a date" ... but if it's talking about date I/O, then absolutely, stick to the nice sane date ISO dates, and use `to_char` and `to_timestamp` where other formats are required for talking with clients.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

yyyy-mm-dd is the recommended format for date field, its the ISO 8601 format.

You can change the format in the postgresql.conf file.

The [document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) states

> The date/time styles can be selected by the user using the SET
>   datestyle command, the DateStyle parameter in the postgresql.conf
>   configuration file, or the PGDATESTYLE environment variable on the
>   server or client. The formatting function to_char is
>   also available as a more flexible way to format date/time output.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you try and modify environment variable `PGDATESTYLE` ?

Comment: In `postgresql.conf` i change style to `datestyle = 'sql, dmy'` and nothing heppens.

Comment: I could think of the following possibilities. The server was not restarted after editing postgresql.conf. Perhaps, set a date style for the correct database (not the cluster)with an alter database statement if possible 
Finally one small piece, try executing the queries as `psql` if you are not doing it already

Answer (score 23):

you also can use the command

```
set datestyle to [your new datestyle];
```

in the console of postgreSQL.

Comment: This is only a per-session change however.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) function with your date as follows:

```
select to_char(date_column1, 'Mon/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: Okey its works. But i have a huge number of columns in my select and now i cant use * for select all columns. Its possible to change datestyle in postgres not in query?

Comment: @KliverMax no, postgres stores the date as it does, but it's formatted on retrieval.

Answer (score 6):

If at all possible, don't use `DATESTYLE`. It'll affect all code in your session, including things like stored procedures that might not be expecting it and might not have set an explicit overriding `DATESTYLE` in their definitions.

If you can, use `to_char` for date output, and `to_timestamp` for date input whenever you need to use any date formats that might be ambiguous, like `D/M/Y`. Use ISO dates the rest of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I change this variable in postgresql.conf and it works!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For data import you can use:
SET datestyle = 'ISO, DMY';

and then your copy table import CSV statement