# Postgres import data- datetime variable out of range

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to use PgAdmin 4 to import some data from a csv file into a table. The following error is being returned for a column named "Event_Date"

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "26/04/2017 21:10:00"
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

"Event_Date" is formatted as "timestamp (6) without time zone". What is the proper format that should be used for this type of date? Also, the date part of the "Event_Date" variable is in DMY, not MDY. Could that be causing problems? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change datestyle in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244460/how-to-change-datestyle-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just type `SET datestyle` in the same session you're issuing `COPY`:

```
SET datestyle = 'DMY';
SELECT '26/04/2017 21:10:00'::TIMESTAMP;
```

More info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html).