# How to upload data into a Redshift Table with a Date Format 'MMDDYYYY'

Tags: date, amazon-redshift, psql

I need to upload a Data in the format 'MMDDYYYY'

current way code i am using to send via psql

```
SET BaseFolder=C:\


psql -h hostname -d database -c "\copy test_table(id_test, 
colum_test,columndate DATEFORMAT 'MMDDYYYY') 
from '%BaseFolder%\test_table.csv' with delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;"
```

here test_table is the table in the postgres DB

> ```
> Id_test: float8
>
> Column_test: float8
>
> columndate: timestamp
> ```

```
id_test colum_test  colum_date

94  0.3306  12312017

16  0.3039  12312017

25  0.5377  12312017

88  0.6461  12312017
```

i am getting the following error when i run the above query in CMD in windows 10

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "12312017"
>
> HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
>
> CONTEXT:  COPY test_table, line 1, column columndate : "12312017"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change datestyle in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244460/how-to-change-datestyle-in-postgresql)

Comment: I don't understand that - there is no clause `DATEFORMAT 'DDMMYYYY'` in `COPY`, and you should get a syntax error. Is this really PostgreSQL? What do you get for `SELECT version();`?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html ?..

Answer (score 1):

The [DATEFORMAT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-dateformat) applies to the whole COPY command, not a single field.

I got it to work as follows...

Your COPY command suggests that the data is **comma-separated**, so I used this input data and stored it in an **Amazon S3 bucket**:

```
id_test colum_test,colum_date
94,0.3306,12312017
16,0.3039,12312017
25,0.5377,12312017
88,0.6461,12312017
```

I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    foo_id BIGINT,
    foo_value DECIMAL(4,4),
    foo_date DATE
    )
```

Then loaded the data:

```
COPY foo (foo_id, foo_value, foo_date)
FROM 's3://my-bucket/foo.csv'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/Redshift-Role'
CSV
IGNOREHEADER 1
DATEFORMAT 'MMDDYYYY'
```

Please note that the recommended way to load data into Amazon Redshift is **from files stored in Amazon S3**. (I haven't tried using the native `psql` copy command with Redshift, and would recommend against it — particularly for large data files. You certainly can't mix commands from the Redshift COPY command into the psql Copy command.)

Then, I ran `SELECT * FROM foo` and it returned:

```
16  0.3039  2017-12-31
88  0.6461  2017-12-31
94  0.3306  2017-12-31
25  0.5377  2017-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a horrible format for dates. Don't [break](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-FORMAT) your date type, [convert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-formatting.html) your data to a saner format.

```
=> select to_date('12312017', 'MMDDYYYY');
  to_date
------------
 2017-12-31
```

Comment: So make a text column in a temporary and convert it.

Comment: from the line `columndate DATEFORMAT 'MMDDYYYY'` in post I make assumption the OP won't find it obvious :)