# PostgreSQL extract day of week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to run a query on PostgreSQL 10 to extract the day of the week. My query is below

```
select distinct extract ( ISODOW from to_date(substring(<column_name>, 1,10),'mm/dd/yyyy')) as day_code
from <table_name>
```

However I am getting an error stating

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "01/16/2019"
SQL state: 22008
```

Is there anything I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Why are you storing DATE values in a varchar column? That is a really bad idea. You should use a `date` or `timestamp` type (then you wouldn't have this problem).

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244460/how-to-change-datestyle-in-postgresql. You seem to have `DATESTYLE` set to `EUROPEAN`, which means `01/16/2019` is looking for the first day of the sixteenth month, and, of course, throwing an error.