# How to convert a string to a date PostgeSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have this format '15.02.2018 4:34'. How to get the format '15.02.2018' ?
I tried cast as date, but it gives an error.

ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "15.02.2018 4:54"

Comment: [to_date](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me

```
select to_Date('15.02.2018 4:34' , 'DD-MM-YYY')
```

But, please check your datestyle. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244460/how-to-change-datestyle-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

To add to @MitkoKeckaroski answer:

```
show datestyle ;
 DateStyle 
-----------
 ISO, MDY

select '15.02.2018 4:34'::timestamp;
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "15.02.2018 4:34"
LINE 1: select '15.02.2018 4:34'::timestamp;
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

set datestyle = 'ISO, DMY';
SET

select '15.02.2018 4:34'::timestamp;
      timestamp      
---------------------
 2018-02-15 04:34:00
```