# pq: date/time field value out of range: "22/02/2022"

Tags: postgresql, go, google-cloud-sql

I have this query:

```
    l.loyaltycard_number, l.recipt_no, 
    l.totaltrans_amount, l.amount_paid, 
    l.reward_points, l.redeemed_points,
    cashier FROM loyalty l
    JOIN warehouses w
    ON l.machine_ip = w.machine_ip
    WHERE l.machine_name = $1 
    AND redeemed_points != $2
    AND trasaction_time BETWEEN $3 AND  $4
    ORDER BY trasaction_time DESC;
```

I have  HTML datepickers  for the transaction_time that is in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

anytime I select a date range that the first number is greater than 12, (22/02/2022).
I get the above error.
I suspected the formatting was the problem.

I found in the docs how to set the postgresql date style to DMY. After doing that, I get the same error.

However, when I run the same query in Postgres cli like so:

```
SELECT w.machine_name, l.trasaction_time,
        l.loyaltycard_number, l.recipt_no, 
        l.totaltrans_amount, l.amount_paid, 
        l.reward_points, l.redeemed_points,
        cashier FROM loyalty l
        JOIN warehouses w
        ON l.machine_ip = w.machine_ip
        WHERE l.machine_name = 'HERMSERVER'
        AND redeemed_points != 0
        AND trasaction_time BETWEEN '14/11/21' AND  '22/02/22'
        ORDER BY trasaction_time DESC;
```

I get the expected result. I don't know what I am doing wrong.
I want to know how I can make the database treat the date from the datepicker as dd/mm/yyyy instead of mm/dd/yyyy. I am using google cloudsql Postgres

This is the code for the handler that gets the data from the datepicker

```
err := r.ParseForm()

    if err != nil {
        app.clientError(w, http.StatusBadRequest)
    }

    startDate := r.PostForm.Get("startDate")
    endDate := r.PostForm.Get("endDate")
    outlet := r.PostForm.Get("outlet")
    reportType := r.PostForm.Get("repoType")

    if reportType == "0" {
        rReport, err := app.models.Reports.GetRedeemedReport(startDate, endDate, outlet, reportType)
        if err != nil {
            app.serverError(w, err)
            return
        }

        app.render(w, r, "tranxreport.page.tmpl", &templateData{
            Reports: rReport,
        })
    } else if reportType == "1" {
        rReport, err := app.models.Reports.GetAllReport(startDate, endDate, outlet)
        if err != nil {
            app.serverError(w, err)
            return
        }

        app.render(w, r, "tranxreport.page.tmpl", &templateData{
            Reports: rReport,
        })
    } else {
        app.render(w, r, "tranxreport.page.tmpl", &templateData{})
    }
```

Comment: Does it work in CLI with `BETWEEN '14/11/2021' AND  '22/02/2022'`? With the full year?

Comment: Where did you set the `DateStyle`?

Comment: Changing `DateStyle` is an option but consider using [`TO_DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-formatting.html) (e.g. `BETWEEN TO_DATE($3,'DD/MM/YY') AND TO_DATE($4,'DD/MM/YY')` (or even better passing in the date as ISO 8601/`time.Time`).

Comment: Alex_O have you tried @Brits suggestions? Kindly let us know if it worked on your end.

Comment: Thank you @Brits. you suggestion worked as expected, I am grateful. I will explore the option of converting the date into ISO time too and see. For now this has solved my problem.

Comment: Yes @MabelA. it worked as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I used  Ubuntu terminal and connected to CloudSql via cloud proxy. I ran the query from my local terminal.

Comment: No it still gives me the same error @Adrian

Comment: @Alex_O don't use localized strings in the first place, and definitely not 2-digit years. This is a bug that can only work by accident. Use parameterized queries and pass actual date values instead of strings. [HTML's  datepickers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) return time in ISO8601 format, even if they display it in a localized format. How did your form end up with the display text instead of the field value?

Comment: @Alex_O please post your HTML/JavaScript code and the actual data access code. The `Get` methods should *not* be using strings to pass dates. At the very least use `time.Parse` to parse the form string into a proper `Time`

Comment: @Alex_O and please, please don't use two-digit years. There's absolutely no reason to reintroduce the Y2K bug, and no way to defend using two-digit years. Is that `45` 1945 or 2045? What if that's a birth date? Or a life insurance expiration date? This isn't nitpicking - In January 2020 the big news in IT was that [Lloyd's](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/) internet banking and the UK's DVLA [crashed because they used two-digit dates](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/13/y2k_dvla/). That string takes more space than a `Time`, so even that argument doesn't hold up

Comment: @Alex_O as for why you shouldn't use ambiguous localized string literals, [Family wrongly accused of uploading pedo material to Facebook – after US-EU date confusion in IP address log](https://www.theregister.com/2020/09/15/eu_us_date_format_family_accused/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the comments while it should be possible to change `DateStyle` there are a few issues with this:

- The [`SET datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) command changes the style for the [current session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244460/how-to-change-datestyle-in-postgresql). As the `SQL` package uses connection pooling this is of limited use.
- You [may be able to use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-OUTPUT) "the DateStyle parameter in the postgresql.conf configuration file, or the PGDATESTYLE environment variable on the server" but this may not be available where Postgres is offered as a managed service. Note that making this change also means your software will fail if the parameter is not set (and this is easily done when moving to a new server).

A relatively simple solution is to edit your query to use `TO_DATE` e.g.:

```
BETWEEN TO_DATE($3,'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE($4,'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

However while this will work it makes your database code dependent upon the format of the data sent into your API. This means that the introduction of a new date picker, for example, could break your code in a way that is easily missed (testing at the start of the month works either way).

A better solution may be to use a standard format for the date in your API (e.g. ISO 8601) and/or pass the dates to your database functions as a `time.Time`. However this does require care due to time zones, daylight saving etc.

Comment: This only covers up the real problem - using localized strings instead of properly typed query parameters. It can only work by chance too - there's no guarantee that this string is in `DD/MM/YY`. Never mind reintroducing the Y2K bug. Is that `45` 1945 or 2045? What if that's a birth date? Or an insurance expiration date? This isn't nitpicking - In January 2020 the big news in IT was that [Lloyd's](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/) internet banking and the UK's DVLA [crashed because they used two-digit dates](https://www.theregister.com/2020/01/13/y2k_dvla/)

Comment: The ambiguous format issue isn't nitpicking either - AT BEST a mixed up value will throw an error. The far worst case though is it will get parsed in an incorrect date with [pretty ugly consequences - people were arrested because 10/11/16 was translated the wrong way](https://www.theregister.com/2020/09/15/eu_us_date_format_family_accused/).